# Build quality for VR does not correspond to the specified one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm coming here because I didn't find a solution to my problem, and I would like your opinion. I'm building a Unity SteamVR project, with a specified quality level (Fantastic for example).

However, the quality of the built game does not correspond to the specified one. (I see it with the shadows and the aliasing that are lower than expected). I'm sure to specify the good quality level, it's marked with a green tick.

Do I need to specify the quality level in an other way ? Is this a well known bug ? Is it related with SteamVR ?

I am using Unity 2017.

Brett

Answer (score 0):

The quality settings for VR is different from a normal standalone build. The VR quality heavily depends on the render scale which controls the texel:pixel ratio before lens correction is applied. Note that this will also affect performance.

You can change it with:

[`VRSettings.renderScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/VR.VRSettings-renderScale.html)

Last time I checked, the render scale default value on SteamVR is 1. *The more you increase this, the better the quality you get*. I recommend you change it to about **1.5** and see if the performance looks fine with that value. If not, keep increasing.

```
void Awake()
{
    VRSettings.renderScale = 1.5f;
}
```

You can learn more about Unity's render scale and see example of VR image outputs based on its values [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/getting-started-vr-development).

Comment: The render scale corresponds to the density of pixel. The density of the built game is good enough. My problem is that there is no realtime shadows, just the one contained in the lightmaps. For the antialiasing, it seems to be desactivated. What I mean is that the quality level seems to be the lowest one, no matter what I specify. And in the editor, there is no quality problem. 

Of course I can modify the graphical properties of the lowest level, but it's just hack.

Comment: 1.You didn't mention you were not getting shadows at-all in your question. You simply said the quality is not good and not changing from the settings. 2.Avoid real-time shadows in VR. Use Lightmapping. I will leave this answer here as that might be useful to others with quality issues on VR.

Answer (score 0):

I found a (bad) solution. If I deactivate all the levels except the one I targeted, the building process use the expected quality.

[image]

On the left, the specified level quality is not used when I build my game. On the right, the specified level quality is used to build my game, but I need to previously deactivate all the others levels.

Answer (score 0):

I also find a workaround. I set the settings manually via script. For example anti-aliasing to 8.

`QualitySettings.antiAliasing = 8;`